# Python argparse type and choice restrictions with nargs > 1

Tags: python, argparse

The title pretty much says it all. If I have nargs greater than 1, is there any way I can set restrictions (such as choice/type) on the individual args parsed?

This is some example code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--credits', nargs=2,
    help='number of credits required for a subject')
```

For the -c argument I need to specify a subject and how many credits are required. The subject should be limited to a predefined list of subjects, and the number of credits required should be a float.

I could probably do this with a subparser, but as it is this is already part of a sub-command so I don't really want things to get any more complicated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can validate it with a [custom action:](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action)

```
import argparse
import collections


class ValidateCredits(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option_string=None):
        # print '{n} {v} {o}'.format(n=args, v=values, o=option_string)
        valid_subjects = ('foo', 'bar')
        subject, credits = values
        if subject not in valid_subjects:
            raise ValueError('invalid subject {s!r}'.format(s=subject))
        credits = float(credits)
        Credits = collections.namedtuple('Credits', 'subject required')
        setattr(args, self.dest, Credits(subject, credits))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--credits', nargs=2, action=ValidateCredits,
                    help='subject followed by number of credits required',
                    metavar=('SUBJECT', 'CREDITS')
                    )
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
print(args.credits.subject)
print(args.credits.required)
```

---

For example,

```
% test.py -c foo 2
Namespace(credits=Credits(subject='foo', required=2.0))
foo
2.0
% test.py -c baz 2
ValueError: invalid subject 'baz'
% test.py -c foo bar
ValueError: could not convert string to float: bar
```

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this, and man your solution is good. Wish I could give you more upvotes! Thanks!

Comment: Note for posterity: adding `metavar=("SUBJECT", "CREDITS")` to the `add_argument` call will make the help show `--credits SUBJECT CREDITS` rather than `--credits CREDITS CREDITS`.

Answer (score 22):

Side note, because this question turns up when searching for "argparse nargs choices":

A custom action is only needed if the nargs arguments require a heterogenous type validation, i.e., the argument at index 0 should be a different type (here: limited type of subjects) than the argument at index 1 (here: float) etc.

If a homogenous type validation is desired, it is sufficient to combine `nargs` with `choices` directly. For instance:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--list-of-xs-or-ys",
    nargs="*",
    choices=["x", "y"],
)
```

would allow anything like `--list-of-xs-or-ys x y x y`, but would complain if the user specifies anything else than `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 0):

A caller of a Action class only catch a ArgumentError.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py#L1805

For expecting to catch an exception by a caller, You should raise as following in your custom action.

`raise ArgumentError(self, 'invalid subject {s!r}'.format(s=subject))`

Answer (score -2):

i suppose you could try this - in add_argument(), you can specify a limited set of inputs with choice='xyz' or choice=[this, that]
as described here:
http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#choices

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--credits', choice='abcde', nargs=2, 
    help='number of credits required for a subject')
```

Comment: This would set the same choice for every arguments. That is not what is requested in the question.