# Can I use add_argument twice for the same positional arg with different nargs?

Tags: python, argparse, argv

I'm writing a CLI tool that needs to accept 2 different flavors of a "search" command as its first argument : one that requires exactly 1 extra positional argument and the other exactly 3 extra positional arguments.

e.g. : `tool search x` or `tool search x y z` would both be valid (**not** `tool search x y`), but route to completely different functionality.

There are also a few other commands besides "search". I also need to be in control of the exact error messages and exit codes (I think this is possible with ArgumentParser.exit() )

How would you implement this with argparse ? Intuitively I think I need to use `add_argument` twice for `search` with different `nargs` and possibly different `dest`, but not sure if this is possible.

Honestly I was going to do this directly with `sys.argv` but I keep reading how naughty that is (I can see why, but this seems like a special case), so just checking if this is easy to do with argparse as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not capture all arguments, and then validate them with your own custom logic (prior to the script's main execution)?

Comment: Good idea, but is there much value left in using argparse when you do that ?

Comment: `argparse` is most useful if you're parsing command line options. If your only use is for positional arguments, you're getting less value out of it. But, you still get thinsg like: (a) help output with --help (b) errors for unknown options (c) an easy way to add optional arguments in the future.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624034/python-argparse-type-and-choice-restrictions-with-nargs-1 might help - not sure if it's possible to accomplish this natively.  I think you're going for something like `choices=[["x"], ["x", "y", "z"]]` but I don't think that's possible.  In either case, you'd want to hinge your script's execution flow based off of which choice is provided - so I'd be inclined to create a custom validation script and route execution based off that.

Comment: You can use `add_argument('foo', nargs=2)` and `add_argument('foo', nargs=4)` together, but that means you want 6 strings total.  There's no either/or when it comes to specifying `positionals`.